# Output of echo in a while loop inside a busybox container does not change

Tags: containers, kubectl, busybox

I am trying to get a busybox **Pod** to output some logs in a JSON format every second while updating the `time` timestamp and the `msg` value for debugging purposes.

For that, I create the following `hello-pod`

```bash
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: hello-pod
spec:
 containers:
 - name: count
   image: busybox
   args: [
    /bin/sh,
    -c,
    'i=0; while true; do echo "{\"time\":$(date +%s),\"msg\":\"This is my dummy log number $i\"}"; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done'
   ]
EOF
```

I expect the Pod to write the following to the standard output

```
{"time":1662474158,"msg":"This is my dummy log number 0"}
{"time":1662474159,"msg":"This is my dummy log number 1"}
{"time":1662474160,"msg":"This is my dummy log number 2"}
```

However, I'm getting the same log output, `time` stays the same and `i` has no value.

```
{"time":1662473834,"msg":"This is my dummy log number "}
{"time":1662473834,"msg":"This is my dummy log number "}
{"time":1662473834,"msg":"This is my dummy log number "}
```

After looking a bit at [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685187/date-string-is-not-updating-within-while-true-do-loop), I tried updating the echo statement in the third argument with `echo "{\"time\":my-time}" | sed "s/my-time/$(date +%s)/"` which I expected to replace the `my-time` string with the new current time but I still get the same result. (The first echo as output every second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `kubectl apply -f -`, you will see what's being `cat`'d to `kubectl` and, I think you'll find that the variables have been substituted once when the file was generated.

This should work:

```bash
echo 'apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: hello-pod
spec:           
 containers:
 - name: count
   image: busybox
   args: [
    /bin/sh,
    -c,
    "i=0; while true; do echo {\"time\":$(date +%s),\"msg\":\"This is my dummy log number ${i}\"}; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done"
   ]' | kubectl apply --filename=-
```

My personal preference is to avoid combining JSON `[...]` with YAML and to use YAML's pipe (`|`) to more cleanly lay out the script:

```bash
echo 'apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: hello-pod
spec:           
 containers:
 - name: count
   image: busybox
   command:
   - /bin/sh
   - -c
   args:
   - |
     i=0
     while true
     do
       echo "{\"time\":$(date +%s),\"msg\":\"This is my dummy log number ${i}\"}"
       i=$((i+1))
       sleep 1
     done
' | kubectl apply --filename=-
```